# Is it bad to have a captive dependency on DbContext instance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

Maybe this question has some explanation around but could not find the best solution to this:

I was reading this [blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) from Mark Seemann about the captive dependencies and as far as I understand at the end of the post he comes to conclusion never use or at least try to avoid the captive dependencies otherwise there will be troubles (*so far is OK*). Here is another [post](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html) from Autofac documentation.

They suggest using captive dependencies only by ***purpose*** (*when you know what you are doing!*). This made me think about a situation I have on my website. I have like 10 services, all of them rely on `DbContext` for database operations. I think they could easily be registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` if I fix the problem for `DbContext` not to hold it forever in memory attached to my services. (I am using Autofac in my case). So, I thought a good starting point would be to create all of these as per lifetime instances and the `DbContext` as instance per request. Then in my services, I would use something like that:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IDbContext _dbContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDbContext>();

    private MyModel GetMyModel() => Mapper.Map<MyModel>(_dbContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

And then in my startup class I have:

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().As<IDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Does this pattern work correctly, I mean not keeping the `dbContext` forever attached to any service, so it will be disposed at the end of the request and if it works, is there any performance issue from this line:

```
 private readonly IDbContext _dbContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDbContext>();
```

compared to constructor injection(There are many invocations from dbContext to database so I am afraid to get `IDbContext` every time I want to use it because it might be resource consuming) ?

The reason I want `dbContext` to be instance per request and not instance per dependency is that I have implemented the unit of work pattern on top of the `dbContext` object.

A normal method in my controller would look like:

```
public ActionResult DoSth()
{
     using(var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkManager.NewUnitOfWork())
     { 
          //do stuff
          try
          {
              unitOfWork.Commit();
              return View();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              unitOfWork.RollBack();
              LoggerService.Log(e);
              return View();
          }
     }
}
```

If this works fine then there is another issue I am concerned of. So, if I can make my services as instances per lifetime (*except DbContext*), is there any issue to apply async-await on every method inside of the services to make them non-blocking methods. I am asking this if there is any issue using async-await for the `dbContext` instance, so, for example, I would have something like this:

```
public async MyModel GetMyModel()
{
   var result = //await on a new task which will use dbcontext instance here
   return Mapper.Map<MyModel>(result);
}
```

Any advice or suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: On a slight tangent your `MyService` example is using Service Locator as apposed explicit dependency principle.

Comment: @Nikosi yes I understand but is it acceptable to use this way only when it comes to dbContext ?

Comment: Usually it is advised against due to tight coupling. Although targeting core you should also read this article from docs about DI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#replacing-the-default-services-container focus on the llifetime scope section

Comment: If `MyService` depends on on `dbContext` and is registered with a longer lifetime than `dbContext` then `dbContext` is effectively registered with the longer lifetime with respect to `MyService`. e.g. If `dbContext` is per request and `MyService` is a singleton then `dbContext` is captured and effectively a singleton with the respect to `MyService`

Comment: @JSteward thats the problem I am trying to solve :). Thats why I have this line of code `private readonly IDbContext _dbContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDbContext>();`

Comment: Please note that the call to `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDbContext>` is an implementation of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) (Mark's blog). You should always prefer Constructor Injection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach the issue from a distance.

There are some architectural choices which can make your life easier. In web development it's practical to design your application to have **stateless service layer** (all the state is persisted in DB) and to fit the **one HTTP request, one business operation** principle (in other words one service method for one controller action).

I don't know how your architecture looks (there's not enough info in your post to determine) but chances are it meets the criteria I described above.

In this case it's easy to decide which component lifetime to choose: DbContext and service classes can be transient (*InstancePerDependency* in terminology of Autofac) or per request (*InstancePerRequest*) - it doesn't really matter. The point is that they have the same lifetime so **the problem of captive dependencies doesn't arise at all**.

Further implications of the above:

- You can just use ctor injection in your service classes without worries. (Anyway, service locator pattern would be the last option after investigating lifetime control possibilities like [lifetime scopes and IOwned<T>](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html).)
- EF itself implements the unit of work pattern via *SaveChanges* which is suitable most of the cases. Practically, you only need to implement an UoW over EF if its transaction handling doesn't meet your needs for some reason. These are rather special cases.

> [...] is there any issue to apply async-await on every method inside of the
>   services to make them non-blocking methods.

If you apply the async-await pattern consistently (I mean all async operations are awaited) straight up to your controller actions (returning *Task<ActionResult>* instead of *ActionResult*), there'll be no issues. (However, keep in mind that in ASP.NET MVC 5 async support is not complete - [async child actions are not supported](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/61).)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as always, is it depends... This configuration can work if:

1. Your scopes are created within the request boundary. Is your unit of work creating a scope?
2. You don't resolve any of your InstancePerLifetimeScope services before creating your scope.  Otherwise they potentially live longer than they should if you create multiple scopes within the request.

I personally would just recommend making anything that depends on DbContext (either directly or indirectly) InstancePerRequest.  Transient would work as well.  You definitely want everything within one unit of work to be using the same DbContext.  Otherwise, with Entity Framework's first level cache, you may have different services retrieving the same database record, but operating on different in-memory copies if they're not using the same DbContext.  Last update would win in that case.

I would not reference your container in MyService, just constructor inject it.  Container references in your domain or business logic should be used sparingly and only as a last resort.

Comment: `IUnitOfWorkManager` would be intance per lifetime as well. The method I resolve `IUnitOfWork` is only to provide a new instance everytime it is being used:`     public IUnitOfWork NewUnitOfWork()
        {
            return new UnitOfWork(_context);
        }`